# Python : The merge of two lists and maintain the order

Tags: python, job-scheduling

I want to merge 2 lists in one list, and in this one list I can find the elements of the two lists at the same order for example :
input :

```
['10','22','3','4','5']
['22','3','5']
```

the output should be:

```
['10','22','3','4','5']
```

The goal is to combine multiple sequences of tasks to do in one sequence in which we can pass all the tasks.
I used the code below but it repeats many tasks that we can eliminate logically, I want to optimize it more.

```
 def merge(L,R):
    S=[]
    n=min(len(L),len(R))
    for i in range(n):
        if L[i]==R[i]:
            S.append(L[i])
        else: 
            S.append(L[i])
            S.append(R[i])
    if len(L)>len(R):
        return(S+list(k for k in L[n:]))
    if len(R)>len(L):
        return(S+list(k for k in R[n:]))
    if len(L)==len(R):
        return(S)

# n is the number of tasks written in a text file before tasks and each task is written on a line

n=int(input())
resultat=[]
for i in range(n):
    line=input().split()
    resultat=merge(resultat,line)
print(resultat)
```

Comment: Could you use a more instructive example?  The second list is already a sub sequence of the first list so it's not really clear what you're merging here.

Comment: okay here is a clair example : the input is :
['A' ,'B' ,'C' ,'D' ,'F']
['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'F']
['A', 'C', 'B', 'F']
['A','C' ,'D' ,'E' ,'F']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] . the output should be :[ 'A','C','B','C','D','E','F']
the program supposed to merge many lists

Comment: Your description and your examples disagree with one another. You can use the union of sets to create a list of unique tasks: e.g. `list(set(l1).union(l2))`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear.

In case you want to merge the lists of tasks and execute each task once only, we can use sets:

```
l1=['A' ,'B' ,'C' ,'D' ,'F']
l2=['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
l3=['A', 'B', 'C', 'F']
l4=['A', 'C', 'B', 'F']
l5=['A','C' ,'D' ,'E' ,'F'] 
l6=['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

import itertools as it
s = set(it.chain(l1, l1, l3, l4, l5, l6)))
print(list(s))
```

produces

```
['A', 'B', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C']
```

Else, if you want a unique set of tasks at each step of every list in parallel

```
lo = [e for t in it.zip_longest(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6) for e in set(t) if e is not None]
print(lo)
```

produces

```
['B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'F']
```

In case the input lists vary in number, create a list of lists and check out [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)